# How do I add smooth transitions to this script

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add smooth transitions when display block and hide:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".userBox").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.inBox').css({ display: "block" });
        $(this).find('.boxDisc').css({ display: "block" });
    $(".userBox").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('.inBox').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).find('.boxDisc').css('display', 'none');
    });
  });
});
```

Because right now it's instant and doesn't look good.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [jQuery fading methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".userBox").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.inBox').stop().fadeIn('fast');
        $(this).find('.boxDisc').stop().fadeIn('fast');
        $(".userBox").mouseout(function () {
            $(this).find('.inBox').stop().fadeOut('fast');
            $(this).find('.boxDisc').stop().fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Example:

**http://jsfiddle.net/L9t4J/**

Answer (score 0):

You could try fadeIn and fadeOut:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".userBox").mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('.inBox').fadeIn(500);
        $(this).find('.boxDisc').fadeIn(500);
    $(".userBox").mouseout(function () {
        $(this).find('.inBox').fadeOut(500);
        $(this).find('.boxDisc').fadeOut(500);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using jQuery methods such as `show('slow')`, `hide('slow')`, `toggle('slow')` will make transitions smoother.

http://api.jquery.com/show/

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Other useful, playful and great methods are .animate() and jQuery ui's slide effects (https://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/)

Cheers!

Edit: I was going to write about the fadeIn and fadeOut methods too. But Maurice Perry was quicker to point those out with an example :)

Comment: i tried show('slow') and fadein or out but i'm kinda lost where to put them because whenever i put them they don't work :(